# An optimization problem involving the calculation of MatrixRank gets wrong

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I was trying to solve an optimization problem involving rank of a matrix and experimenting with a very simple one. A 2x2 matrix which contains only one parameter `a11` is `{{a11,2},{2,4}}` and I want to minimize the rank of this matrix. Obviously, the matrix can have a minimum rank of 1 when `a11` equals 1. But when I use the following commands,

```
answ = NMinimize[{MatrixRank[{{a11, 2}, {2, 4}}]}, {a11}]
```

It gives the answer

> {2., {a11 -> 0}}

which indicates a rank of 2 with `a11=0`. I do not quite understand why this is the case. Is it the NMinimize function has difficulties handing the `MatrixRank` computation? Any comment is welcomed.

Comment: The arguments of `NMinimize` are being evaluated first, and with symbolic `a11`, `MatrixRank[{{a11, 2}, {2, 4}}]` immediately evaluates to the constant 2,  so you are effectively doing `NMinimize[2, a11]`.

Comment: For your simple example you can do: `Solve[Det[{{a11, 2}, {2, 4}}] == 0, a11]`

Answer (score 1):

One way to determine matrix rank is to count the number of zero eigenvalues. For the simple case:

```
Select[Table[
   Solve[Eigenvalues[{{a, 2}, {2, 4}}][[i]] == 0, a], {i, 2}], Length[#] > 0 &]
```

This checks to find values of `a` that give zero eigenvalues and selects all those with non-empty solutions.